# How to select userID and user from a table where the userIDs are different

Tags: mysql, sql, userid

I have a table where all the userID's are different as i needed a primary key, but 98 different UserID's link to one username. I need to select one user from a database called `studenttable` but still call the `userID`.

This is a shorter example of the table:

```
    **UserID  Username   Year   Form   Subject1   Subject2    Subject3   Subject4**
      1       John      13      D      Art       French    Psychology  Religion
      2       John      13      D      Art       French    Psychology  Religion
      .
      .
      99      Fank      13      D      Maths     Art       Geography   Biology
      100     Fank      13      D      Maths     Art       Geography   Biology
      .
      .
      198     Max       12      A     Psychology  Maths    Physics     German 
      199     Max       12      A     Psychology  Maths    Physics     German 
      .
      .
      296     Henry     13      D     Psychology  Economics  French    P.E
      297     Henry     13      D     Psychology  Economics  French    P.E
```

and so on....

I want to select all the users from the database that fit a certain criteria, such as, they have to be in **year 13** and in **form D** and do **Psychology** as one of their subject. I then only want to display one of the users that have the same username.

I want the result table to look like:

```
  UserID       Username     Year    Form    Subject 
    1           John         13      D       Psychology
   296          Henry        13      D       Psychology
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Is this jdbc related or just a SQL query?

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your table is that the subject can be in any column of the four columns `Subject1   Subject2    Subject3   Subject4`, for this you can use the `IN` predicate like this:

```
WHERE 'Psyhcology' IN(Subject1, Subject2, Subject3, Subject4)
```

So that your full query would be:

```
SELECT 
  UserId,
  UserName,
  Year,
  Form,
  'Psyhcology' AS Subject
FROM tablename
WHERE Year = 13
  AND Form = 'D'
  AND userID IN(SELECT UserID 
                FROM tablname 
                WHERE 'Psychology' IN(Subject1, Subject2, Subject3, Subject4));
```

**Note that:** This query will give you duplicate rows for the `Name` because you have multiple names with the different id's:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ USERID  ║ USERNAME  ║ YEAR  ║ FORM  ║  SUBJECT   ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║      1  ║ John      ║   13  ║ D     ║ Psyhcology ║
║      2  ║ John      ║   13  ║ D     ║ Psyhcology ║
║    296  ║ Henry     ║   13  ║ D     ║ Psyhcology ║
║    297  ║ Henry     ║   13  ║ D     ║ Psyhcology ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

But if you want to get unique rows, you have to select one id for each group of name, for example the `MIN(USerID)`:

```
SELECT
  MIN(UserId) AS UserId,
  UserName,
  Year,
  Form,
  'Psyhcology' AS Subject
FROM users
WHERE Year = 13
  AND Form = 'D'
  AND userID IN(SELECT UserID 
                FROM users 
                 WHERE 'Psychology' IN(Subject1, 
                      Subject2, 
                      Subject3, 
                      Subject4))
GROUP BY Username, Year, Form, Subject;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f6e56/12)

This will give you:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ USERID  ║ USERNAME  ║ YEAR  ║ FORM  ║  SUBJECT   ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║    296  ║ Henry     ║   13  ║ D     ║ Psyhcology ║
║      1  ║ John      ║   13  ║ D     ║ Psyhcology ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

---

But, I'd rather [*normalize*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the table instead, by creating a new table for `subjects`:

**`Subjects`**:

- `SubjectId` PK,
- `SubjectName`.

Then your table would look like:

- `UserId`,
- `UserName`,
- `Year`,
- `Form`,
- `SubjectId` a foreign key references the subjects table.

This will make it easier to query the two tables. For example, if you want to search for the users who take a specific subject, you can simply join the two tables:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(u.UserId) AS UserId,
  u.Username, 
  u.Year, 
  u.Form, 
  s.Subjectname
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN subjects AS s ON u.subjectId = s.subjectId
WHERE s.subjectname = 'Psyhcology'
  AND u.Year = 13
  AND u.Form = 'D'
GROUP BY u.Username, u.Year, u.Form, s.Subjectname;
```

This will give you the same results as before:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═════════════╗
║ USERID  ║ USERNAME  ║ YEAR  ║ FORM  ║ SUBJECTNAME ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║    296  ║ Henry     ║   13  ║ D     ║ Psyhcology  ║
║      1  ║ John      ║   13  ║ D     ║ Psyhcology  ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═════════════╝
```

Here a demo with the modified tables' structures:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a35de/5)

Answer (score 0):

The aggregator `MIN` below is arbitrary, it will pick the smallest value for identical records. Use any other aggregator if you need, e.g. `MAX`:

```
SELECT MIN(UserId), Username, Year, Form, Subject1, Subject2, Subject3, Subject4
FROM studenttable 
GROUP BY Username, Year, Form, Subject1, Subject2, Subject3, Subject4
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select all the users from the database that fit a certain
>   criteria, such as, they have to be in year 13 and in form D and do
>   Psychology as one of their subject. I then only want to display one of
>   the users that have the same username.

So you want to found these rows form your table:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(s.userId) FROM studenttable s 
    WHERE s.year = 13 AND s.form='D' 
      and (s.subject1='Psychology' OR s.subject2='Psychology' 
        OR s.subject3='Psychology' OR s.subject3='Psychology')
```

[DISTINCT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php) allows is used in a SQL query to remove duplicates from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
select distinct(UserID), Username, Year, Form, Subject from studenttable where Year = 13
  and Form = 'D' and userID in(select UserID 
            from studenttable
             where 'Psychology' in (Subject1, 
                  Subject2, 
                  Subject3, 
                  Subject4));
```

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal why it is required to check against each subject? We three basic conditions and based on that the data will be fetched from the database.